# ODP.NET Stored Procs and Optional Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net

I tried searching and haven't found a definitive answer to my issue. I am making the switch from SQL Server to Oracle but still using C# for the front end. I am using ODP.Net. I have a stored proc in Oracle like this:

```
Create or Replace
Procedure GetFoo
   (cur_z OUT sys_refcursor,
    pub_date   IN   varchar2,
    fname      IN   varchar2 default null,
    lname      IN   varchar2 default null,
    phone      IN   varchar2 default null
   )
 IS
  BEGIN
    ---get some data
  END;
```

fname, lname, and phone are optional parameters. In my C# code I set the OracleCommand.BindByName = true which I have read should allow me to exclude sending any parameters in which there are no values to be sent in. For example, I would just need to send in the cursor, the pub_date and phone to search for a record that matches just the phone number. However, when calling this from C# though and only adding the parameters for the cursor, pub_date and phone I keep getting the error: "wrong number or types of arguements in call to 'GetFoo'. Then if I send in cursor, pub_date, and fname and leave the rest empty I get results and all works well. It seems that you can not skip over any parameters regardless of the BindByName setting. If this is correct behavior then I can work around it but it seems a bit odd (well at least from my SQL Server experience) and I want to make sure I am not missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: just wondering have you tried executing sp by skipping some param and commenting following line OracleCommand.BindByName?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK the `BindByName` is intended for use in cotrast to binding by position... it has nothing to do with any default params or similar...

Comment: Thanks. So if there are optional parameters in your SP you have to send them in through ODP.NET regardless, right?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, `BindByName` **does not work** for stored procedures - only for queries.

But it really shouldn't matter to you. You should only be calling this SP from a single method in your application anyway. Use default parameters in the signature of that method, and just always pass all parameters to ODP.Net.

```
object GetFoo(DateTime pubDate, string fName = null, string lName = null, string phone = null)
{

}
```

Do that, forget about it and use your time for more important problems.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the binding to Oracle Parameters in a stored procedure is based only on position.

This means that you have to add your parameters in the same order as they are declared in the procedure and Oracle will not care about the name you set your parameter to.

When you set the binding to BindByName, you can add parameters in any order, as long as they have the same name. This is, in my opinion a lot better than the default.

However, setting BindByName to True or False won't affect wether a parameter is required or no.